# Generate ASP.NET WebForms control HTML attribute at runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am trying to generate `placeholder` attribute value at runtime.
The code does not generate an error but does not create the `placeholder` attribute as well. Control is properly rendered except it is missing `placeholder`.

What am I doing wrong here?

`<asp:TextBox type="text" placeholder='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>' autocomplete="off" required="required" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="txtDate1" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" />`

Comment: But when I use `placeholder` with static value `placeholder="zzz"` all works. So seems like it is supported.

Comment: Call `DataBind()` in Page Load if the TextBox is not in a GridView, Repeater etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have this:

```
placeholder='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>'
```

However, note the use of "#". That means you using a data binding expression, but in above, you not really say using controls inside of a grid view or whatever.

Hence, the above can work, but you want to use a "=" in place of the "#". So, such a server-side expression is allowed, and should work.

The characters are:

```
 <%= Your server-side expression here %>

 <%# %>   For data binding (inside repeater, Grid View etc.).

 <%   %>   For inserting a server-side code block into markup.
```

So, from above, I would suggest that for the most part, you probably in most cases use the first 2 above syntax examples. I tend to avoid using the above 3rd option and example. I tend to avoid placing code inside the markup since that markup is already rather messy anyway.

So, for example, you can place this markup in a page:

```
<h3><%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></h3>
```

Result:

[image]

So, note in above use of the "=" in code, and not a "#".